# Use Azure Service Bus without 'direct' internet connection possible, SendVia?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

An Azure Service Bus/Queue question...

We have systems (SystemA) that have 'no' internet connection direclty, but can connect to another server (SystemB) via whatever ports we decide to open.

SystemB can connect to internet and Azure no problem.

But I can't see how to use SendVia so that I can say

SystemA, Send a Queue message Via SystemB.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions)

What would we install on SystemB... or is Send Via just for, well, I don't know what it's for if not this...

Would we have to roll our own solution for SystemA->SystemB part? Or am I missing somthing?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send-via is not what you think it is. It only can operate on the same namespace and connection.

> or is Send Via just for, well, I don't know what it's for if not this...

The feature is intended for transactional processing of the incoming message with the dispatch of the outgoing messages.